# spring+Hibernate one to many count rows

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, orm

I have a One To Many relationship between "Post" and "Comment" entities in hibernate. One Post Can have many comments (Post) 1 - N (Comment), therefore comment holds foreign key to post (post_id). The thing is that When i'm fetching post list for my controller, with each post i also want to include number of COMMENTS assigned to this post. So if there is some post list, i want to attach to the data number of comments below that post.

I've created PostWithCommentsCountDTO with additional field that can hold number of comments, i've done converters etc.

BUT Where and how should i actually fetch the number of comments, how can i actually do that ?

Whole architecture looks like this
Controllers - PostWithCommentsCountDTO - PostService - PostRepository - Post 
Controllers - CommentDTO - CommentService - CommentRepository - Comment

Comment: Please include enough information to help other reproduce the problem, including any relevant code. See this for help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read point 15.6 [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)
You can create constructor with all fields for PostWithCommentsCountDTO. After that You can use it inside HQL query as it is described in the link I've added. In you query you can join Post and Comments by 'post_id', group them by 'post_id' and use count(post_id) in select statement.
So Your query will look like :

```
select new PostWithCommentsCountDTO (p.id, /and all other fields.../ , count(post_id)) from Post as p left join Comments as c on p.id=c.post_id where /some where statement if needed .../ group by c.post_id
```

This means that You can collect Your DTO already in repository level:

```
public List<PostWithCommentsCountDTO> getWithCommentsCount(...){
     return (List<PostWithCommentsCountDTO>) getSession().createQuery(...).setParameter(...).list();
}
```

Comment: isn't returning dto from repository a "bad practice", because i've heard you must return entity ?

Comment: @Rickmoriarty for general methods such as `getAll(...)` , `getById(...)` and similar to them You should return entity, but  for some specific method where you don't need all data from table better to use DTOs.

Comment: @Rickmoriarty For example You need to select all names of product  and their count from some orders table if You get all orders from DB and group them on service layer You have to get lot of unneeded data from DB which increase Your traffic and time for method execution. If Your DB isn't in same machine as Your application  execution time will be bigger and app will be slower. But You can do simple ` group by ... ` and ` count (...) ` in DB server and get only aggregated data from DB which will work faster and use less traffic between application and DB.

Comment: @Rickmoriarty This makes solution this returning DTO from repository level more optimized and potentially reduce amount of bugs in future when somebody updates DB during Your request. In summary : for general getting methods better to return entity from repository but for specific calculation or aggregation methods better to return pre-calculated DTO from repository